# How to fire itemStateChanged event when setting the item's initial value?

Tags: java, itemlistener

I've implemented a `java.awt.event.ItemListener` that responds to `itemStateChanged`. It seems to execute as expected for *changes* to `JComboBox`  However, the event does not fire for the first value that I assign to the combo box.

I couldn't find a way to run this on [ideone.com](https://ideone.com), but the code below can be compiled and executed as-is. Put it in "MyDialog.java," compile with `javac.exe *.java` and execute with `java MyDialog`. The `DoStuff` method will not be executed when the dialog initializes. When the user changes the combo box, however, the event will fire.

```
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class MyDialog extends JDialog
{   
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MyDialog dlg = new MyDialog();
        dlg.setVisible(true);
    }

    class MyListener implements java.awt.event.ItemListener
    {
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event)
        {
            if (event.getSource() == myComboBox &&
                event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED )
            {
                DoStuff(event);
            }
        }
    }

    JComboBox myComboBox;

    public MyDialog()
    {
        this.setSize(100,100);

        myComboBox = new JComboBox();
        myComboBox.addItem("Option 1");
        myComboBox.addItem("Option 2");
        this.add(myComboBox);

        MyListener listener = new MyListener();
        myComboBox.addItemListener(listener);

        myComboBox.setSelectedItem("Option 1");

        // EXPECT: DoStuff() was executed
        // GOT: DoStuff() was not executed
    }

    public void DoStuff(java.awt.event.ItemEvent event)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "DoStuff() was reached.");
    }
}
```

How do I get the `DoStuff` event to fire when the dialog initializes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because "Option 1" is default/selected option already, that's why

```
 myComboBox.setSelectedItem("Option 1");
```

will not trigger any Item changed event. Change the code to

```
 myComboBox.setSelectedItem("Option 2");
```

and it will trigger the `doStuff()` method, because item is indeed changed from current selection.

Comment: Thanks, that helps me understand why it's happening. However, if I do want "Option 1" as the default, is my only recourse to switch to "Option 2" and switch back? This seems a bit odd. @AlanHay's suggestion may also work, but I may have to rework some things.